# Django runtime error during insertion from admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a django model as follows:

```
class M1(models.Model):
    m1code = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    m1title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    m1description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.m1title

class M2(MPTTModel):
    m1 = models.ForeignKey(M1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, unique=False)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        degreeroot = M2.objects.get(name=self.m1.m1title)
        requirement = M2.objects.create(name=self.name, parent=degreeroot, m1=self.m1)
```

Here i have 2 models with one model M2(MPTT model) has a foreign key to M1. Whenever i make an entry into M2 from the admin, I want django to automatically enter the value into the parent in M2 based on the selection of m1.

Here i have defined a save() to do this. But when i am running it in my admin, the program is going into a **runtime error**.

```
RuntimeError at /admin/acadprog/m2/add/
maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Hint: what happens when the save method creates another M2 object?

Comment: I am not sure if i understood correctly. Why would it create another M2 object?

Comment: Because that's what you've told it to do. If you don't want to do that, why are you calling `M2.objects.create`?

Comment: because i am trying to save the entry under the parent obtained from M1. is there another way to do this? basically i am trying to create a child to the name(which is a title from M1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to create a new entry, since that will always lead to an infinite recursion. You just want to set `self.parent`, then call the superclass save method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.parent:
        self.parent = M2.objects.get(name=self.m1.m1title)
    return super(M2, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: hi Daniel, can i get some help with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30432599/django-code-weird-behaviour